# Java class is not a valid argument to the jvm

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-karaf, karaf

I have a wrapper.conf file that contains the following (note I've omitted irrelevant entries such as .1, .2, .3, etc.):

```
set.default.JAVA_HOME=E:\DATA\Dev\jdk1.7.0_65
# Java Application
set.default.KARAF_BASE=E:\hsip-base-5.3.1.1b
wrapper.working.dir=%KARAF_BASE%
wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.apache.karaf.shell.wrapper.Main
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/karaf-wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_HOME%/lib/karaf.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/lib/karaf-jaas-boot.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/karaf-wrapper-main.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/

# JVM Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.4=org.apache.karaf.main.Main
```

On starting apache karaf I'm getting the following error:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2017/01/30 14:42:52 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
WARN   | wrapper  | 2017/01/30 14:42:52 | The value of     property 'wrapper.java.additional.4', 'org.apache.karaf.main.Main' is not a valid argument to the jvm.  Skipping.
```

The jar file it is looking for and the class within are fine (%KARAF_BASE%/lib/karaf-wrapper-main.jar)

Is fine. A colleague had a similar problem and it was JVM related but cannot remember what.

Does anyone know where I can even start with this because it should work. I have java 8 on my machine, but I have removed all references to it and my JAVA_HOME is pointing at this version 7, don't know if that makes a difference.

Note, the actual stack traces are something like

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 | ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [1] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/1.2.8 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] package; (package=javax.net.ssl))
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 | org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] package; (package=javax.net.ssl)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 |   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 |   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 |   at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 |   at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/30 15:11:48 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you add the lines that contains wrapper.java.additional.4?

Comment: sorry, that would help :) I've done it, it's just a repeat of the mainclass, hence why I forgot it.

If it helps, it's the exact same file as everyone else, but it just doesn't work on my computer...

Comment: Is there any gaps in the numbers? i.e. you have wrapper.java.additional.1 to 4 ?

Comment: Yes, they're all there. As I said it's the same file as my colleagues, but theirs works... I've also updated to include one of the many errors that result after this. I can only presume they are linked.